# top 10 by category mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-variables

I have a table where I have to get top 10 in each category based on the amount spent by a person in that category. My sample data is

```
person category amount
roger  perfume   20
jim    perfume   50
joe    tv        5
jim    tv        25
kathy  car       40
alicia perfume   100
```

I gotta get this in one query. I know limit does not work on **amount** like **limit amount 10**. Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variables:

```
SELECT person, category, amount
FROM (
  SELECT person, category, amount,
         @rn := IF(@cat = category, @rn+1,
                   IF(@cat := category, 1, 1)) AS rn
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @cat := '') AS vars
  ORDER BY category, amount DESC) AS t
WHERE t.rn <= 10
```

`@rn` is used in order to enumerate rows within each `category` slice by descending `amount` order.

Hence, the outer query returns the 10 highest ranking rows per `category`. If less than 10 records exist for a specific category, then all of these records are returned.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f611f/5)

Comment: the solution is working in terms of ranking but still not displaying 10 rows as needed.

Comment: @ash There was a small bug in the query, fixed it. Do you want *I have to get top 10 in each category* or *10 rows in total* returned?

Comment: Yes top 10 in each catory

Comment: somehow the count is not working. I am still getting more than 10 rows. I am unable to share the data as it's more than 100k rows.

Comment: @ash Of course you get more than 10 rows, that's the real intention, isn't it: *get top 10 in **each** category*?

Comment: So may be I should have said limit to top 10 in each category

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95389/discussion-between-ash-and-giorgos-betsos).

Comment: sorry man, the code you gave me worked. The dumb me was using the wrong category. Appreciate your help brother.

Answer (score -1):

since category appears multiple times, you will need to group by category, summing up the amounts.  Then sort on it and keep the number of rows you want.

I think the following will work:

```
SELECT category, SUM(amount) as amount
FROM mytable
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: this wont work as I am not trying to sum up the amount. I want to display top 10 purchase for each category in separate rows.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Select Top 10
      person, category, sum(amount) as Amount
      from Table
      group by person,category
```